# separate lists by class and nth-child

Tags: css

i think it´s stupid question but i cant find answer for that..
question is...
if i have 2 lists but i want to spcify different values for both lists... how will be the code?

```
   <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>

</ul>

<ul class="class">
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
</ul>
```

i tried...
... to select ul by CLASS. NOT WORKED

```
.class:nth-child () {}
```

... select li.. NOT WORKED

```
.class li:nth-child () {}
```

... other select li... NOT WORKED

```
.class:li:nth-child () {}
```

any ideas?

Comment: What are you trying to select `:)`?

Comment: the second UNORDERED list O:)

Comment: I wonder if you didn't make a typo. There should be no space between `nth-child` and `()`. It should be `.class li:nth-child()`.

Comment: Do you want second `ul` or `li` from second `ul`?

Comment: yeah. u right about the NO SPACE.. i tried now.. still not working... :/

Comment: Hard to understand, what you are actually trying to do. I _guess_ this is what you are looking for: `ul.class li { ... }`

Comment: i tried to select the second ul by this class... cause.. if i use ul.. or li... it will select all LI in document :/

Comment: @Mrazik0 please be clear, share **all the code** to reproduce your issue. (see [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: arkascha.. i tried ur way.. still not working..  i just wonder if i can select the LI of the second UL... i thougt it can be done by specifying the second UL by class... any better idea? O:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to select second `ul` with [`:nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)  [`DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/tu7zxkqx/)

```css
ul:nth-child(2) {
  background: green;
}
```

If you want to select `li`'s from second `ul` [`DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/tu7zxkqx/1/)

```css
ul:nth-child(2) > li {
  background: green;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

Or you can use `class` to select second `ul` [`DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/tu7zxkqx/2/)

```css
ul.class {
  background: green;
}
```

Or if you want to select second `li` from second `ul` [`DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/tu7zxkqx/3/)

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

ul.class > li:nth-child(2) {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>

<ul class="class">
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: nice.. and.. 
example... i want select EXACTLY second UL... that. every SECOND LI wil be blue.... how it will be?

Comment: Like this https://jsfiddle.net/tu7zxkqx/4/ or https://jsfiddle.net/tu7zxkqx/5/ or https://jsfiddle.net/tu7zxkqx/6/